How to get sum of rows based on a key value?
I am looking for a formula to get the sum of protein column for individual recipes.
Need some help.


To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is creating a markdown table. Use this table generator to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Another way is to share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing


You may try:
=sumif(scan(,J:J,lambda(a,c,if(cell("prefix",c)<>"",c,a))),"Veggie Omlette",N:N)

